# Error when refering to the pointer to a structure after using memcpy()

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy, distributed-system

```
void Process_joinreq(void *env, char *data, int size)
{
    // env = the node who has received the msg. Introducer
    member *node = (member *) env;

    /* address of the member who sent a join request to the introducer.*/
    address *addr = (address *)data;

    // memberlist is a structure
    size_t msgsize = sizeof(messagehdr) + sizeof(struct memberlist);
    messagehdr *msg=malloc(msgsize);

    printf("\nIn Process_joinreq function, Sending reply from the introducer to ");
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d:%d \n", addr->addr[0], addr->addr[1],
            addr->addr[2], addr->addr[3], *(short *)&addr->addr[4]);

    msg->msgtype=JOINREP;

    // add the new nodes row in the membership list and call the logNodeAdd function
    memcpy(&node->membershiplist[node->countofmembers].addr,addr,sizeof(address));
    node->membershiplist[node->countofmembers].heartbeatcounter += 1;
    node->membershiplist[node->countofmembers].timestamp = getcurrtime();
    node->membershiplist[node->countofmembers].isfailed = 0;
    node->countofmembers++;
    logNodeAdd(&node->addr,addr);

    printf("\nThe number of members in the list of introducer is d\n",node->countofmembers);

    //msg should be the membership list.
    memcpy((char *)(msg+1), &node->membershiplist, sizeof(memberlist));
    /* send JOINREQ message to introducer member. */
    MPp2psend(&node->addr, addr, (char *)(msg), msgsize);

    free(msg);
    return;
}
```

I am trying to implement a membership protocol in distributed systems. The above code describes a function written to process the requests of the processes other than the introducer process trying to join the network. I am able to get a reply to each process from the introducer that it has successfully joined the network.

The second step involves sending the membership list from the introducer to all the remaining nodes. When I try to access the node->membershiplist in the Process_joinrep function it has garbage value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's no enough info here to answer the question. For example, the data being point to by `env` might not actually be a valid `member`. We don't know what the various `sizeof` expressions are. There could be alignment and/or strict aliasing problems. Try to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)

Comment: The code starting "add the new nodes" is treating the `node->membershiplist` as an array of something; but your `memcpy` just copies the first element of that array (assuming `sizeof(memberlist)` is the same as `sizeof(struct memberlist)`) . Are you sure you have correctly allocated memory for the array.

Comment: Why is one pointer argument a `void *` and the other a `char *` even though both are pointers to structures?  Consistency suggests they should be the same type, and modern style (meaning 'in the last 25 years') suggests they should both be `void *`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to so so. Could you please post mising code for `address`, `member`  and other classes we have missed? you last `memcpy` looks fishy. We can't tell as we don't see the required classes.

Comment: Hi guys, The problem was not in the memcpy. While accessing the "data" variable in the process_joinrep function I was treating it as a single pointer. I had to cast it as a double pointer to reference the membershiplist of the node. Thanks